# Remove grey border from Facebook lightbox pop up

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

How can i remove the dark grey border that surrounds the Facebook lightbox pop http://jsfiddle.net/pyqNg/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Just Change like this

```
.mdbox-title {border:20px solid white;}   //or specify .mdbox-title{border:0px;}
```

Comment: But you have great code.it works for me.accept it if it also for you

Comment: I was looking to remove the dark grey border seen here http://i47.tinypic.com/23rogvn.png

Comment: It works, but it's the wrong border i'm wanting removed. Please look here http://i47.tinypic.com/23rogvn.png

Comment: i also give another ans like .mdbox-title{border:0px solid #DDDDDD}..??i think it may hepled you..??

Comment: It's not the title border i'm wanting removed. It's the dark grey border surrounding the lightbox. Example here: i47.tinypic.com/23rogvn.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16480/discussion-between-jbnbtw-and-gautamdharmapuri)

Answer (score 0):

so you wnat to [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/pyqNg/1/)

```
 $('.mdbox-title').css("border","0px solid #DDDDDD");
```

Comment: yes so many try after i will find solution see [this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/pyqNg/6/)