# URL check in VBA error

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below. And I receive error

> "run-time error '-2146697211 *800c0005)'': the system cannot locate the resource specified"

I do not know how to solve it thanks in advance for any help. Line in which error is handled is `httpRequest.send`

```
Function pullSomeSite(urlcheck As String) As Boolean

Dim httpRequest As xmlhttp
Set httpRequest = New xmlhttp
Dim URL As String

URL = urlcheck
With httpRequest
    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send !!!!!!here code stops!!!!!!!
End With
With httpRequest

    While Not .readyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Wend

    'Debug.Print .Status

    If .Status = 200 Then
        While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0    '<---------- wait again
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        pullSomeSite = True
     Else
     pullSomeSite = False

    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure your URL is working?

Comment: Swap `Dim httpRequest As xmlhttp : Set httpRequest = New xmlhttp` with `Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP60 :  Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP60` and ensure that "Microsoft XML, v6.0" is selected as a reference (in Tools > References) Using just "XMLHTTP" is equivalent to the old "XMLHTTP30" from "Microsoft XML, v3.0" but should still have worked

Answer (score 0):

Test this :

```
Sub Test_URLExists()
  Dim url As String

  url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940044/url-check-in-vba-error"
  MsgBox url, vbInformation, URLExists(url)

  url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345678/url-check-in-vba-error"
  MsgBox url, vbInformation, URLExists(url)
End Sub
```

here is how to test an URL with a function :

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    URLExists = False
    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

Comment: Could you explain more plz... What seems to be the problem? Is there an error (which and where)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xmlhttp data type use object. 
Use the below code.
. You need to give input as "http://google.com"

```
Sub test1()
a = pullSomeSite("http://www.flipkart.com")


MsgBox a
End Sub


Function pullSomeSite(urlcheck As String) As Boolean

Dim httpRequest As Object

 Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'Set httpRequest = New xmlhttp
Dim URL As String

URL = urlcheck
With httpRequest
    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send '!!!!!!here code stops!!!!!!!
End With
With httpRequest

    While Not .readyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Wend

    'Debug.Print .Status

    If .Status = 200 Then
        While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0    '<---------- wait again
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        pullSomeSite = True
     Else
     pullSomeSite = False

    End If
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Could you please check it again